# How to remove every inactive/unused screens in python?

Tags: python, scripting, windows

in blender you can easely create thousands of screens. 
i'd like to have every screens from bpy.data.screens that are not visible deleted, how can i do that ?

i know that

```
for screen in bpy.data.screens:
    bpy.ops.screen.delete({'screen': screen})
```

delete every single screens, that's a goo thing, but i don't know how to detect the visible/invisible ones ?

Comment: maybe check their size?

Answer (score 3):

I came across same issue and this was one of the only things relatively close, so I'd like to share how I cleaned up the screens that should be orphans in my Blender file.

So first to determine which screens were in use, open the outliner or add one to the current workspace and set it to "data api" view like this

[image]

Then once you have it open you need to expand the window or windows sections. So if you only use one monitor then there should only be one, if you have two monitors and have opened a *new window* then there should be one for each open separate instance window like here is mine.

[image]

So what we want to do is like I have in the screenshot is find the screen being used by each window and rename it. Now the reason I have named it the same as the workspace, is the window manager tab in api data is unique to each workspace.

So workspace name followed by master for main screen and slave for the *new window* secondary screen.

Then just work through each workspace, repeating the same above process, until we have all the active and open screens renamed. We can then check in the screens list to make sure we got all of them.

[image]

Like this, see all the leftover unused "default" copies, that should be orphans since they are from a "new window" I have closed but seem to still have a user.

Once we have done this all we need to do is manually force clear all the users for the unused screens with the python console, so open one up on any workspace and using this command swapping nameofscreen with the names from the above list.
`bpy.data.screens['nameofscreen'].user_clear()`

[image]

Now back to the to the outliner mode and this time switch it too orphan data and you will now see a list of the the orphan screens, hit purge, that will delete them from file. Then we can go back to the API data outliner mode and we should have a nice clean screen list like this.

[image]

This was done using a custom build version 2.9 alpha but should work in any 2.8+ versions.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Thanks for taking the time to write an answer. In the future please always prefer builtin image tools to embed pictures directly into your post, rather than external linking to them. That way users don't have to click through to other sites, and they never get lost to link rot making the post hard to follow or downright unreadable. Once you have sufficient reputation you'll be able to upload more than one picture per post.

Comment: Thank you so much for fixing it for me, I was actually looking for embedded images but wasn't sure how to yet!

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Thank you again Sir <3

Answer (score 0):

In my case this will work by defining which screens you want to remove and run script below, then purge them.
I have several screens named "temp" and "Default." that I want to remove.

[image]

**So the script is :**

```
import bpy

for scr in bpy.data.screens:
    if "temp" in scr.name or "Default." in scr.name:
        scr.user_clear()
```

This will allow the screens listed as Orphan Data, so we can Purge them later on